# What is the pdftotext encoding corresponding to pdf's Winansi?

Tags: pdf, encoding, pdftotext

I am trying to convert a German-language pdf to text with Poppler's utility pdftotext, but I do not get correct characters for any of the characters with diacritics.

pdffonts myfile.pdf 
gives the following result:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Advgsr                               Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    100  0
Advgsb                               Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    105  0
Advgsi                               Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    110  0
Advmtr                               Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes    115  0
Advma92                              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no     120  0
AdvPS_SY                             Type 1C           Custom           yes no  yes     51  0
Advgr                                Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes no  no      56  0
```

my version of pdftottext defaults to utf-8, so I thought I would try to extract text using winansi encoding. I have no idea how to figure out if the main text is what uses the winansi-encoded font, but perhaps it is.
However, I can't find an encoding corresponding to winansi (or its other names) in  pdftotext.
pdftotext --listenc gives me the following list of available encodings:

```
UCS-2
ASCII7
Latin1
UTF-8
ZapfDingbats
Symbol
Big5
EUC-JP
EUC-CN
ISO-2022-KR
Big5ascii
KOI8-R
GBK
ISO-8859-6
Latin2
Windows-1255
ISO-8859-7
ISO-8859-8
ISO-8859-9
ISO-2022-JP
TIS-620
ISO-2022-CN
Shift-JIS
```

I can't see any equivalent to winansi. Does anyone know?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: "Encoding" is not end of it – the specifications allow per-codepoint customization as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29468049/2564301) for a small but complete lecture. If this is to work for a single file, you might as well do a manual replace on the results.

Comment: I had read that answer before posting---I am aware of the complexity of the problem. I just wanted to give it a shot with pdfttotext---but can't find anything corresponding to winsansi. Perhaps there is none

Comment: "WinAnsiEncoding" is not *entirely* made up by Adobe, it is based for the largest part on one of these standard encodings. If you look up the unexpected received values for common accented characters, you may be able to find the correct one right away.

Comment: Ah wait. The `Latin1` in your list is a common name for Windows code page 1252, which is what WinAnsiEncoding uses. If you tried that already, then it's a customized encoding.

Comment: Indeed I tried Latin1 already and it didn't work. It must be a custom encoding

Comment: So that at least answers your question. But if you can share the PDF somewhere we can take a look if it contains enough information to restore it.