# zlib will inflate a stream but text encoded in <> will stay in hex form

Tags: c++, pdf, encode, zlib, inflate

I am using embarcadero 10.3.1 c++, using zlib inflate. this code works, however, text in hex form is encoded. after the code below you will find the problem pdf ver. 1.7

```
        size_t outsize = (streamend - streamstart) * 10;
        char *zoutput = new char[outsize];
        memset(zoutput,0,outsize);

        z_stream zstrm;
        zstrm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.zfree = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.opaque = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.avail_in = (unsigned int)(streamend - streamstart + 1);
        zstrm.avail_out = (unsigned int)outsize;
        zstrm.next_in = (Byte *)(streamstart);
        zstrm.next_out = (Byte *)zoutput;

        int rsti = inflateInit(zstrm);

        if (rsti == Z_OK) {
            int rst2 = inflate(zstrm, Z_FINISH);
            inflateEnd(zstrm);

            if (rst2 >= 0) {
                size_t totout = zstrm.total_out;
                   }
             }




==inflated version using zlib===========================================
```

This pdf information has sensitive personal data, the output below was generated from an encoded stream, the output below is a pdf decode readable stream.  The problem is, the zlib library did not decode text or float values, lines like Tm\n Tj\n.  inside <> E689A388849981A68193A261D489A283 will not decoded.  Tm and Tj are instructions that the pdf engine will move the a point (Tm) and Tj begins the process of displaying the text encoded in .

Is the pdf a multi level encoded file? or what will make zlib decode or decompress the hex strings.  I tried ASCII85 and HEXtoASCII.  I will continue reading the Adobe specification.

this code I preceded the code at the top, to isolate 
        char bac[] = " ";

```
        streamstart = bac;
        streamend = bac+(strlen(bac)*sizeof(char));
```

The line has a transaction data like that found in a back statement, or name and address.  I can not find the encoding strategy for <>, like <~~> => ASCII85.

The block stream has a filter of data type flatecode.
23 0 obj
<>stream

============output below from zlib inflate.=========================

```
> Blockquote

        =========right above===============================
        <C1C3C3D6E4D5E3> this I can not get converted to text.
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with all inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Alan, thanks for taking the time and responding.  What I am missing from extracting text from a pdf, is encoding, level of encoding, or data type when passing the hex string to zlib, I am supposed to use gzip or another library?

Comment: The answer is in this blog "Encoding of PDF text string" https://stackoverflow.com/q/29467539/11369490

Comment: <C1C3C3D6E4D5E3> spells "account"